# how to stop powershell invoker in C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm invoking powershell command with C#, and powershell command is invoked background. and i want to terminate the background thread. everytime, i terminate the background thread, the powershell is still running which result in that i can't run that thread again. is there any method to terminate powershell execution?

the background thread as follows:

```
Task.run(()=>{ while(...) {...                             
if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
}}}); 

Task.run(()=>{ 
    while(...) { powershell.invoke(powershellCommand);// it will execute here, I don't know how to stop. 
} })
```

Comment: What command do you start that runs indefinetly?

Comment: a script that i write. and it will execute for a long time

Comment: I don't know if the script is some kind of loop, but if it is, I think  you should consider placing the loop logic in your C# code, so its easier to break from that part of the code. Alternatively, you might run your PS Script as a [PowerShell Background Job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878288(v=vs.85).aspx). You can start and stop a job with simple, direct return, commands, so your `invoke()` won't run forever.

Comment: You could also call BeginInvoke() to start your script asynchronously, see [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn614674(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 6):

I know I'm late to the party but I've just written an extension method which glues up the calls to `BeginInvoke()` and `EndInvoke()` into Task Parallel Library (TPL):

```
public static Task<PSDataCollection<PSObject>> InvokeAsync(this PowerShell ps, CancellationToken cancel)
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        // Do the invocation
        var invocation = ps.BeginInvoke();
        WaitHandle.WaitAny(new[] { invocation.AsyncWaitHandle, cancel.WaitHandle });

        if (cancel.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            ps.Stop();
        }

        cancel.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        return ps.EndInvoke(invocation);
    }, cancel);
}
```

Comment: I know this post was 6 years ago, but having spent ages trying to find a way to handle cancelling a long running PowerShell command in my VB.NET app, and not getting any responses to my questions on various forums, I finally stumbled across your extension method answer here and it solved my problem and works very well - so just wanted to say thank you !!!!

Answer (score 5):

Stopping a PowerShell script is pretty simple thanks to the [`Stop()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.powershell.stop(v=vs.85).aspx) method on the PowerShell class.

It can be easily hooked into using a `CancellationToken` if you want to invoke the script asynchronously:

```
using(cancellationToken.Register(() => powershell.Stop())
{
    await Task.Run(() => powershell.Invoke(powershellCommand), cancellationToken);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Task.Factory.FromAsync`:

```
await Task.Factory.FromAsync(shell.BeginInvoke(), shell.EndInvoke)
    .WaitAsync(cancellationToken)
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

This allows the cancellation token to be registered elsewhere in the code so additional side effects can be added when execution is cancelled if desired.